# Firebase AuthUI Inicio de Sesión Error Desconocido

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Desde que actualicé la libreria de Firebase Auth a la versión 4.2 estoy teniendo  un "error desconocido" cuando quiero salir de la actividad de iniciar sesión de Firebase presionando el botón de "ir para atrás". Lo extraño es que antes de esta versión de la libreria funcionaba perfectamente.

Otra cosa que vi es que hasta que no se inicia sesión correctamente, no se muestran en el "Logcat" de Android Studio los log.v que puse cuando el usuario cancela la actividad de inicio de sesión. Es decir, una vez que se inicia la sesión correctamente, se muestran todos los log.v juntos.

¿Cuál puede llegar a ser el problema? Estuve buscando pero no he encontrado ninguna respuesta que me funcione.

Gracias!!!

Este es el error:

```
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.UserCancellationException: Unknown error
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.SignInKickstarter.onActivityResult(SignInKickstarter.java:184)
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity.onActivityResult(KickoffActivity.java:81)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5634)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3637)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3684)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Y el código en mi app:

**build.grade (module:app)**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
```

**onCreate()**

```
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in set layout visible
                mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                // Choose authentication providers
                List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build()
                );
                // Create and launch sign-in intent
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setLogo(R.drawable.fondo_inicio_sesion)
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
```

**onActivityResult()**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        // Successfully signed in
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            finishAffinity();
            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {
                // User pressed back button
                Log.v("singInError","sign_in_cancelled"+String.valueOf(resultCode));

                return;
            }
            if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                Log.v("singInError","no_internet_connection");
                return;
            }
            Log.v("singInError", "Sign-in error: ", response.getError());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Esa es la traza completa del error? Convendría que la pongas completa, aunque sea larga.

Comment: Cuando presionas el backbutton los usuarios no se desloguean, lo que estas haciendo es volver a la layout de inicio de sesion pero el token de inicio de sesion que usa auth para cada usuario sigue activo, lo que deberias hacer es desloguear al usuario cuando hace hacia atras con mAuth.signOut();

Comment: @GastónSaillén gracias por tu comentario. No estoy usando el backbutton para cerrar sesión, sino para salir del UI de inicio de sesión cuando aún no hay ninguna sesión iniciada. Es decir, con este código (antes de la actualización de la libreria) le daba la opción al usuario de que si no quería iniciar sesión pueda salir de la app con el backbutton. Después de la actualización ésto no funcionó más. Entonces si un usuario abre la app y no quiere iniciar salir no tiene forma de salir de la app. Entra en un loop.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu comentario. Sí, esa es la traza completa del error.